# fetching and viewing data from database in ci

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have  `subjects` table like this

```
id  parent_id subject_title
1   0         maths
2   1         algebra
3   0         English
4   3         essay
```

how to show those subjects having `id=0` as heading and other subjects below heading subjects like

```
heading       maths
sub-heading   algebra
```

Comment: can you please add your code what you have done so far??

Answer (score 0):

its up to you how you get the record . if its a array you should use an if array index  . something like that `

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++ ) {
 if($data[$i][0] ){
 echo "heading : {$data[$i][0]}";
 }else{
 echo "sub-heading   {$data[$i]}"
 }
}
```

this is just an idea and may not work with your code so please modify before using but main idea here that if it match the certain criteria it will display differently 
hope this will help you . thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code based on your table and problem

```
<?php
// Connecting to and selecting a MySQL database
$mysqli = new mysqli('host_name', 'your_user', 'your_pass', 'db_name');

// A connect_errno exists so the connection attempt failed!
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Sorry, this website is experiencing problems."; 
    exit;
}

// Perform an SQL query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM subjects";

if (!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    // The query failed.    
    echo "Sorry, the website is experiencing problems.";
    exit;
}

// Fetch result
while ($subjects = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($subjects['parent_id '] == 0){
        echo "<b>Heading:</b> ".$subjects['subject_title ']."<br>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<b>Sub-heading:</b> ".$subjects['subject_title ']."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```